# Output specific part for each block

Tags: json, linux, curl, jq

I have a json parsed by jq, but I need to go through each block and get the name  and lastModified and then store them so I can delete the zip file which is older then a specific date. For this example lets say 2020-06-25 is an "old package"
So we have da-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip and lastModified 2020-06-25
I need to filter it by all such packages by lastModified  attribute with jq

```
{
    "success": true,
    "results": 6,
    "total": 6,
    "more": false,
    "offset": 0,
    "hits": [
        {
            "path": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/change-editor-user-accounts-1.3.0.zip",
            "excerpt": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/change-editor-user-accounts-1.3.0.zip",
            "name": "change-editor-user-accounts-1.3.0.zip",
            "title": "change-editor-user-accounts-1.3.0.zip",
            "lastModified": "2020-06-25 17:50:12",
            "created": "2020-06-25 17:50:12",
            "size": "36 KB",
            "mimeType": "application/zip"
        },
        {
            "path": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/change-editor-user-accounts-1.3.0.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/thumbnail.png",
            "excerpt": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/change-editor-user-accounts-1.3.0.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/thumbnail.png",
            "name": "thumbnail.png",
            "title": "thumbnail.png",
            "lastModified": "2020-06-25 17:50:13",
            "created": "2020-06-25 17:50:13",
            "size": "2 KB",
            "mimeType": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "path": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/.snapshot/change-editor-user-accounts-1.3.0.zip",
            "excerpt": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/.snapshot/change-editor-user-accounts-1.3.0.zip",
            "name": "change-editor-user-accounts-1.3.0.zip",
            "title": "change-editor-user-accounts-1.3.0.zip",
            "lastModified": "2020-06-25 17:50:13",
            "created": "2020-06-25 17:50:13",
            "size": "7 KB",
            "mimeType": "application/zip"
        },
        {
            "path": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/.snapshot/change-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip",
            "excerpt": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/.snapshot/change-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip",
            "name": "change-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip",
            "title": "change-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip",
            "lastModified": "2020-06-25 17:50:13",
            "created": "2020-06-25 17:50:13",
            "size": "12 KB",
            "mimeType": "application/zip"
        },
        {
            "path": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/change-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip",
            "excerpt": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/change-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip",
            "name": "change-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip",
            "title": "change-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip",
            "lastModified": "2020-06-25 17:50:13",
            "created": "2020-06-25 17:50:13",
            "size": "31 KB",
            "mimeType": "application/zip"
        },
        {
            "path": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/change-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/thumbnail.png",
            "excerpt": "/etc/packages/com.change.aem.platform/change-editor-user-groups-1.7.0.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/thumbnail.png",
            "name": "thumbnail.png",
            "title": "thumbnail.png",
            "lastModified": "2020-06-25 17:50:13",
            "created": "2020-06-25 17:50:13",
            "size": "2 KB",
            "mimeType": "image/png"
        }
]
}
```

Question is question how to create a cycle which will first check contents of the given block

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  What is "old"?  What have you tried? Why have you used the `curl` tag?

Comment: Added more information. Hope it is better understandable and yes I used curl

Comment: The snippet of JSON you showed is not itself valid JSON. As pervthe [mcve] guidelines, please provide a mcve - both input and expected (in this case, perhaps intermediate) output.

Comment: How is it not valid. I copied it from the output?

Comment: Paste the fragment (shown in the Q) into jsonlint.com and you will see it is not valid JSON.

Comment: I updated the full output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq cannot execute a "rm" command, but assuming you are running jq in a bash or bash-like environment, you could proceed as suggested by the following:

```
jq '.hits[] | select( .lastModified[:10] <= "2020-06-25") | .name' | 
  while read -r f ; do
    echo rm "$f"         # `echo` for testing
  done
```

This of course assumes that the .lastModified field starts with the YYYY-MM-DD form of the date. If either any of those assumptions is incorrect, you could adjust the above accordingly.

Comment: For some reason i get jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index boolean with string "lastModified"

Comment: Works!! What does lastModified[:10] mean

Comment: It's taking the first 10 characters of the lastModified key I.e. the date without the time

Answer (score 0):

Basing the jq statement on the example provided, you can pipe the output to awk to do the date comparisons and generate the commands required.

```
cat file | jq -r '.hits[] | .lastModified + ";" + .name' | awk -v compdat="2020-11-20 13:13:45" -F\; '
    
      BEGIN { 
              "date -d \""compdat"\" +%s" | getline csdat 
            } 
      $2 ~ /zip$/ { 
               split($1,dats," ");
               "date -d \""$1"\" +%s" | getline sdat;
               if (sdat < csdat) { 
                                   print "rm "$2 
               } 
             }'
```

One liner:

```
cat file | jq -r '.hits[] | .lastModified + ";" + .name' | awk -v compdat="2020-05-20 13:13:45" -F\; 'BEGIN { "date -d \""compdat"\" +%s" | getline csdat } $2 ~ /zip$/ { split($1,dats," ");"date -d \""$1"\" +%s" | getline sdat;if (sdat < csdat) { print "rm "$2 } }'
```

In the begin block, we generate the passed date (compdat) in epoch format using awk's getline, passing the result of the date command into a variable csdat. Then we take the ; comma separated variables ($1 - lastModified, $2 - name) and again get the epoch version of lastModified, reading the result into a variable csdat. We then compare csdat to sdat and print a rm command for the zip file if sdat is less the csdat.

Once you have verified that the commands display as expected (this part is important!), you can run the actual command by utilising awk's system function, replacing the print for the system function and so:

```
cat file | jq -r '.hits[] | .lastModified + ";" + .name' | awk -v compdat="2020-05-20 13:13:45" -F\; 'BEGIN { "date -d \""compdat"\" +%s" | getline csdat } $2 ~ /zip$/ { split($1,dats," ");"date -d \""$1"\" +%s" | getline sdat;if (sdat < csdat) { system("rm "$2) } }'
```

Comment: I'm trying to work it with curl but I get jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index boolean with string "lastModified"

Comment: You need to sort out the json first. I'm not sure if it part of a larger subset of data?

Comment: I had to take out the commas after each {......} to initially get the json to parse correctly.

Comment: So when doing the curl I should output it to a file and then remove commas?

Comment: If need be yes. Alternatively, try and get the json formatted correctly from the source (the location where you are curling from)

Comment: I updated the json with the full output from the command. I don't quite understand by "formatted correctly"

Comment: I have amended the solution based on your updated json. Also please not that I have discounted entries for png files as you outlined only zip files in the question.